# alguien sabe como configurar el NetBeans para que autocomplete los codigos? he intentado todo lo que he encontrado

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con el netbeans pues cuando voy a realizar algun algoritmo no me auto completa ningun codigo por ejemplo el System.out.print, else, etc . en fin he buscado informacion en internet me he metido a herramientas- editor - code completion - y le he dado el chulo a ventana emergente e autocompletado de codigo y las demas y aun asi no me sale nada[image: en la siguiente imagen muestro como le di chulo en la casilla de autocompletado de codigos pero aun asi no me autocompleta]

Comment: Usé NetBeans por casi un mes, si hay auto completado. Si lo activaste, lamento decirte que es tan poco que parece que no hay, lo hace solo ratos en muy pocas ocasiones.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, uso la versión 11 de Netbeans, he cambiado de todo y nada, no me sugiere ni me autocompleta el código.

Comment: nunca me ha pasado, pero se me ocurre que tienen el módulo de java deshabilitado, en esa ventana que muestran denle click a la pestaña de java

Answer (score 0):

Intenta escribiendo sout (System.out.println)  y le das a la tecla <kbd>tab</kbd>, o si quieres  autocompletar una palabra escribe las primeras letras y dale <kbd>tab</kbd>, pero igual en ocasiones falla aunque tengas todo activado.

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas,

Para que te autocomplete el código, directamente al escribir, ve a preferencias -> Editor -> Code Completion. En el Language elige Java, y en el recuadro que pone "Auto Popup Triggers for Java" escribe: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. (es importante poner el punto final).

Le das a Apply, luego a Ok y listo.